# Não quer salvar dados de formulário em POST ionic + PHP + MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, angularjs, ionic

Tá funcionando do jeito que faço em outos formulários, mas este não sei qual erro estou cometendo.

Tenho uma tabela "fornecedores":

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Um formulário no Ionic, normal:

```
    <ion-view view-title="Cadastrar seu Restaurante" hide-nav-bar="false" >
    <!-- content -->
    <ion-content delegate-handle="top" lazy-scroll  id="cadastrar_seu_restaurante1" class="has-header page-form_cadastrar_seu_restaurante">

    <div class="list list"  >

        <form name="cadastro_restaurante" ng-submit="CadastraRestaurante()">

            <ion-md-input ng-model="cadastra_restaurante.fantasia" name="fantasia" placeholder="Nome Fantasia" highlight-color="energized" type="text" required></ion-md-input>
            <span ng-show="cadastro_restaurante.fantasia.$error.required" class="form-control alert-danger">
                Nome Fantasia obrigatório.
            </span>

            <ion-md-input ng-model="cadastra_restaurante.razao_social" name="razao_social" placeholder="Razão Social" highlight-color="energized" type="text" required></ion-md-input>

            <ion-md-input ng-model="cadastra_restaurante.cnpj" name="cnpj" placeholder="CNPJ" highlight-color="energized" type="text" required></ion-md-input>

            <ion-md-input ng-model="cadastra_restaurante.ie" name="inscricao_estadual" placeholder="IE" highlight-color="energized" type="text"></ion-md-input>

            <ion-md-input ng-model="cadastra_restaurante.email" name="email" placeholder="E-Mail" highlight-color="energized" type="text"></ion-md-input>

            <ion-md-input ng-model="cadastra_restaurante.cep" name="cep" placeholder="CEP" highlight-color="energized" type="text" required></ion-md-input>

            <ion-md-input ng-model="cadastra_restaurante.logradourro" name="logradouro" placeholder="Logradouro" highlight-color="energized" type="text"></ion-md-input>

            <ion-md-input ng-model="cadastra_restaurante.numero" name="numero" placeholder="Número" highlight-color="energized" type="text" required></ion-md-input>

            <ion-md-input ng-model="cadastra_restaurante.complemento" name="complemento" placeholder="Complemento" highlight-color="energized" type="text"></ion-md-input>

            <ion-md-input ng-model="cadastra_restaurante.bairro" name="bairro" placeholder="Bairro" highlight-color="energized" type="text"></ion-md-input>

            <ion-md-input ng-model="cadastra_restaurante.cidade" name="cidade" placeholder="Cidade" highlight-color="energized" type="text" required></ion-md-input>

            <ion-md-input ng-model="cadastra_restaurante.estado" name="estado" placeholder="Estado" highlight-color="energized" type="text" required></ion-md-input>

            <ion-md-input ng-model="cadastra_restaurante.responsavel_contato" name="responsavel" placeholder="Nome do Responsável do Restaurante " highlight-color="energized" type="text" required></ion-md-input>

            <ion-md-input ng-model="cadastra_restaurante.telefone_empresa" name="tel_restaurante" placeholder="Telefone do Restaurante" highlight-color="energized" type="number" required></ion-md-input>

            <ion-md-input ng-model="cadastra_restaurante.telefone_responsavel" name="tel_responsavel" placeholder="Telefone do Responsável" highlight-color="energized" type="number"></ion-md-input>

            <ion-md-input ng-model="cadastra_restaurante.celular" name="tel_contato" placeholder="Telefone do Responsável" highlight-color="energized" type="number" required></ion-md-input>

            <ion-md-input ng-model="cadastra_restaurante.qtd_entregadores" name="qtd_entregadores" placeholder="Quantidade de Entregadores" highlight-color="energized" type="number"></ion-md-input>

            <ion-md-input ng-model="cadastra_restaurante.senha" name="senha" placeholder="Senha" highlight-color="energized" type="password" required></ion-md-input>

            <ion-md-input ng-model="cadastra_restaurante.confirma_senha" name="confirma_senha" placeholder="Confirme sua senha" highlight-color="energized" type="password" required></ion-md-input>


        <div class="item item-button" >
            <button class="button button-full button-assertive ink">Próximo passo (1 de 3)</button>
        </div>        

        </form>

    </div>
    <br/><br/><br/><br/>
    </ion-content>
    <!-- ./content -->
</ion-view>
```

Meu Controller:

```
     $scope.CadastraRestaurante = function (){

     console.log('parte 4');

    var data = {

        fantasia: $scope.cadastra_restaurante.fantasia,
        razao_social: $scope.cadastra_restaurante.razao_social,
        cnpj: $scope.cadastra_restaurante.cnpj,
        ie: $scope.cadastra_restaurante.ie,
        email:$scope.cadastra_restaurante.email,
        cep: $scope.cadastra_restaurante.cep,
        logradourro: $scope.cadastra_restaurante.logradourro,
        numero: $scope.cadastra_restaurante.numero,
        complemento: $scope.cadastra_restaurante.complemento,
        bairro: $scope.cadastra_restaurante.bairro,
        cidade: $scope.cadastra_restaurante.cidade,
        estado: $scope.cadastra_restaurante.estado,
        responsavel_contato: $scope.cadastra_restaurante.responsavel_contato,
        telefone_empresa: $scope.cadastra_restaurante.telefone_empresa,            
        telefone_responsavel: $scope.cadastra_restaurante.telefone_responsavel,
        celular: $scope.cadastra_restaurante.tel_contato,
        qtd_entregadores: $scope.cadastra_restaurante.qtd_entregadores,
        senha: $scope.cadastra_restaurante.senha
    }        

    console.log(data);


    $http.post("http://nhaac.com/food/modulo_restaurante/apis/api_put/cadastra_restaurante_parte1.php", data).success(function(response){
        console.log(response);
        console.log('leu');
        localStorage.setItem("user", JSON.stringify({user: response}));
        console.log('cadastrado com sucesso');
    //    $state.go("nhaac.entrar");
    }).error(function(error){
        console.error(error);
    });
};
```

E meu PHP para pegar estes dados e inserir na tabela:

```
    <?php 

header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");


    include("connection.php");
    $data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));

    $razao_social = $data->razao_social;
    $fantasia = $data->fantasia;
    $cnpj = $data->cnpj;
    $ie = $data->ie;
    $email = $data->email;
    $cep = $data->cep;
    $logradourro = $data->logradourro;
    $complemento = $data->complemento;
    $cidade = $data->cidade;
    $estado = $data->estado;
    $responsavel_contato = $data->responsavel_contato;
    $telefone_empresa = $data->telefone_empresa;
    $telefone_responsavel = $data->telefone_responsavel;
    $celular = $data->celular;
    $qtd_entregadorese = $data->qtd_entregadores;
    $bairro = $data->bairro;
    $numero = $data->numero;
    $senha = $data->senha;

    $q = "INSERT INTO fornecedores (razao_social, fantasia, cnpj, ie, email, cep, logradourro, complemento, cidade, estado, responsavel_contato, telefone_empresa, celular, qtd_entregadores, bairro, numero, senha  ) VALUES (:razao_social, :fantasia, :cnpj, :ie, :email, :cep, :logradourro, :complemento, :cidade, :estado, :responsavel_contato, :telefone_empresa, :celular, :qtd_entregadores, :bairro, :numero, :senha)";
    $query = $db->prepare($q);
    $execute = $query->execute(array(


    ":razao_social" => $razao_social,
    ":fantasia" => $fantasia,
    ":cnpj" => $cnpj,
    ":ie" => $ie,
    ":email" => $email,
    ":cep" => $cep,
    ":logradourro" => $logradourro,
    ":complemento" => $complemento,
    ":cidade" => $cidade,
    ":estado" => $estado,
    ":responsavel_contato" => $responsavel_contato,
    ":telefone_empresa" => $telefone_empresa,
    ":telefone_responsavel" => $telefone_responsavel,
    ":celular" => $celular,
    ":qtd_entregadorese" => $qtd_entregadores,
    ":bairro" => $bairro,
    ":numero" => $numero,
    ":senha" => $senha  

    ));
    echo json_encode($email);
?>
```

mas dá o erro a seguir:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Não consigo entender onde estou errando aqui. Alguém pode ajudar?

Obrigado!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ao inves de JSON.stringify use angular.toJson

Comment: Explique melhor no que se baseia sua resposta, onde aplicar esta correção? Forneça mais detalhes que justifiquem sua resposta.

Comment: Tive o mesmo problema pesquisei no angular. e encontrei o angular.toJson. o funcionou perfeitamente.

Comment: Pessoal, esqueci de agradecer, nunca é tarde. Obrigado pelas ajudas! :)))